# Querying optimal blocksize for dgels in LAPACK

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, lapack

I'm trying to implement a Kalman filter in C using LAPACK, and need to estimate some parameters by regression.  I'm using [dgels](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgels.f) but keep getting an odd segfault when I try to run it.  I thought it might have something to do with the blocksize I was setting in the parameter LWORK, so I tried querying the optimal size by setting LWORK = -1.  According to the documentation, the first element of WORK should then contain the optimal value of LWORK.  But when I try to access WORK[0], I get another segfault, despite having allocated it before calling dgels!  Any clue what gives?  Here's the code, minus the bits where I assign `double *A, *B` and `int p->N`.

```
char T = 'T';  // Transpose A
int n = 1000;
int LWORK = -1; 
int INFO = 0; 
double * WORK = (double *) malloc (200*sizeof(double));
printf("%e\n",WORK[0]); // This works
dgels_(&T, &(p->N), &n, &(p->N), A, &(p->N), B, &n, &WORK, &LWORK, &INFO); 
printf("%e\n",WORK[0]); // This segfaults
```

gcc 4.2.1, Mac OS X Snow Leopard

**Edit:** Turns out Intel has a good example of how to use `dgels` in C [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lapack/mkl_lapack_examples/dgels.htm)

Comment: Can you post (the relevant bits of) your code?

Comment: Common error with Fortran binding is using a wrong width int.

Comment: How would I pass a different width int?  unsigned?  Try a short instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't follow *FORTRAN API* here: arrays are passed as a reference to the first element but you are passing it as a referance to a reference to the first element (i.e. you should use `WORK` instead of `&WORK`).

Also read [DGELS documentation](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/fl/manual/pdf/F08/f08aaf.pdf) to be sure you understand correctly its arguments meaning (e.g. `NRHS`, `LDA`, and `LDB`).

And yes, be careful with *C* `int` size and the fact *FORTRAN* uses *Column-major order* and *C* uses *Row-major order* ([wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)).